# How do I enable data downloads from a jupyter webapp without writing on the server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I am writing a web app with jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, and voila.

In this web app, after taking instructions by the user, the notebook generates some data (a dictionary) that the user needs to download (as a .json file).
The simple solution I found online is to write a file on the server with the content and provide the user with a link. However, I think this is super ugly, and very inefficient or dangerous if many users run the web app at the same time.
I wonder if there is a way to create a download option for the user without writing anything on the server-side.
Does anyone have some clue?

Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo

Comment: Given it's text data, could you copy it to the clipboard instead?

Comment: @ac24 No: the data could occupy hundreds of Mb or even Gb; this is a problem if the user has to copy it manually on a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your file to be downloaded with pybase64 (file=base64.b64encode...) then ipywidgets

```
 HTML("<a download='name.txt' href='data:text/ascii;base64,%s'> download/>" %(file,)}
```